# Extra whitespace under images in Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, removing-whitespace

I have a simple app, which pulls certain images off the web and displays them via WebView with buttons below and a title above. At first, I had an issue of constantly having extra whitespace under the images, which is now resolved.

For reference, the WebView is defined as follows:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/c"
    android:layout_above="@id/b"
    android:layout_below="@id/t"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This relative layout is within another one, I left it out. 
In the Activity I have the following:

```
        WebView img = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        img.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        img.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        img.loadUrl(image);
```

Now to the current issue:

The images I'm pulling and viewing have different sizes. For simplicity, let's talk two sizes - X and Y, with X < Y. Launch, image of size X is displayed as expected, button tapped, image of size Y is displayed as expected, button tapped, if the next image is of size X again, it will be displayed with extra whitespace (always below) filling it up to size Y. It might stay that way for numerous images of size X or randomly go back to normal. Hope I made the issue clear.

Do I have to somehow explicitly reset the bounds? I did my fair share of googling, but can't find the catch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's better to post your solution as an answer and not put it in the question text. This way you can accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, issue resolved. Maybe it'll help someone in the future as well. I added two functions to the WebView call shown above, namely, clearView and clearCache:

```
    WebView img = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    img.clearView();
    img.clearCache(true);
    img.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    img.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    img.loadUrl(image);
```

It didn't help if it was either one or another, only the combination of the two worked for me. feels a little brutal to me, but works.